# Jenkins ERROR: Labels must follow required specs

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to create a pipeline job for `Angular` code to deploy the application into k8 cluster. Below there is a code for pipeline container `podTemplate`, during the build I get the next error.

```
def label = "worker-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(
    cloud: 'kubernetes',
    namespace: 'test',
    imagePullSecrets: ['regcred'],
    label: label,
    containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'nodejs', image: 'nodejscn/node:latest', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
        containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'nodejscn/node:latest', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
        containerTemplate(name: 'kubectl', image: 'k8spoc1/kubctl:latest', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
    ],
    volumes: [
        hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
        hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/root/.m2/repository', mountPath: '/root/.m2/repository')
    ]
) {

    node(label) {
      def scmInfo = checkout scm
      def image_tag
      def image_name
      sh 'pwd'
      def gitCommit = scmInfo.GIT_COMMIT
      def gitBranch = scmInfo.GIT_BRANCH
      def commitId
      commitId= scmInfo.GIT_COMMIT[0..7]
      image_tag = "${scmInfo.GIT_BRANCH}-${scmInfo.GIT_COMMIT[0..7]}"

      stage('NPM Install') {
           container ('nodejs') {
              withEnv(["NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn"]) {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Error from Jenkins:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Labels must follow required specs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set:  Ubuntu-82f3782f-b5aa-4029-9c51-57610153747c
Finished: FAILURE
```

Do I need to mention a `spec` value of my `Jenkins` file?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get:

```
ERROR: Labels must follow required specs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set:  Ubuntu-82f3782f-b5aa-4029-9c51-57610153747c
```

points out quite precisely what can be wrong with your `Pod` template. As you can see in [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overv) to kubernetes documentation given in the `ERROR` message, you need to follow certain rules when defining a `Pod`. `labels` element is a `dictionary`/`map` field that requires you to provide at least one key-value pair so you cannot just write `label: label` in your specification.

You can try to define your `PodTemplate` in `yaml` format (which is mostly used in **kubernetes**) like in [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates) example:

```
podTemplate(yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: some-label-value
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
"""
) {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
      container('busybox') {
        sh "hostname"
      }
    }
}
```

As you can read [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pod-and-container-template-configuration):

> label The label of the pod. Can be set to a unique value to avoid
>   conflicts across builds, or omitted and POD_LABEL will be defined
>   inside the step.

`label` field can be omitted at all so first you can try without it and you shouldn't get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: Labels must follow required specs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set:  Ubuntu-82f3782f-b5aa-4029-9c51-57610153747c
```

Your label `Ubuntu-82f3782f-b5aa-4029-9c51-57610153747c` has a space before Ubuntu which is not valid

But that error message doesn't seem to match the pod definition you posted as there is no mention of `Ubuntu` anywhere. Maybe inherited